# What exactly does this mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm browsing an open source .NET twain wrapper and saw this:

```
[Flags]
internal enum TwDG : short
{                                   // DG_.....
    Control = 0x0001,
    Image = 0x0002,
    Audio = 0x0004
}
```

What exactly does that 'Flag' decorator mean? (Is it called a 'decorator'?)

Also, what does the short mean at the end of the enum declaration?

Thanks!

Comment: Woops! Forgot to format the code!

Comment: It's called attribute. See [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short is another keyword for System.Int16, a two-byte integer ranging from -32,768 to 32,767.  By default, an enum's base type is int; in this case, they're attempting to use a smaller data type to store the enumerator values.

Answer (score 8):

The [Flags Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) is used to allow and decorate the enumeration for bitwise math operations on enum values.

Doing this allows you to add them together, or other operation items.

The Short part defines it as a Short rather than an integer, detail on this is also in the linked URL

Comment: This is not totally accurate. You can perform bit flipping without the attribute. You do get pretty printing with ToString() though of combined members.

Comment: @chibacity: Unless you're entering a code obfuscation contest, I strongly recommend against that.

Comment: @Code I'm not sure I follow you. The answer states that it is "required". It is not. I am not advocating best-practice here.

Comment: @chibacity: My apologies, the answer must have been edited to remove wherever it said this was "required" to perform bitwise operations. I just wanted to make clear that it's far from best practice.

Comment: @Code The answer has not been edited. It states "allow" == "required".

Answer (score 3):

It's an attribute. Although others have said that it is necessary so that you can perform bit flipping operations with the enum, this is not true. You can do this with enums without this attribute.

If you have applied the attribute, you get a different ToString() output on the enum which will pretty-print the combined members of a enum value, e.g. "Blue | Red | Orange", instead of "7".

The "short" keyword means that the type for the enum members will be a [16-bit signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It means that you give a hint, that this enum will be used for "bitwise or" operations

```
var flags = TwDG.Control | TwDG. Image;
Console.WriteLine(flags.HasFlag(TwDG.Image));   // true
Console.WriteLine(flags.HasFlag(TwDG.Control)); // true
Console.WriteLine(flags.HasFlag(TwDG.Audio));   // false
```

More info [FlagAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) (`Enum.HasFlag` was added in Framework 4.0)

Short is saying, that back-type for this enum is not int (which is default option for enums), but short. Also you can specify long, ushort, or any other integer built-in type.

Answer (score 1):

This makes an enumeration a bit-flag.
It means you can combine individual values together.
Like:

```
TwDG value = TwDG.Control | TwDG.Image | TwDG.Audio;
```

Which would give it a value of 7.

Individual enumeration values usually have a value of `2^n`. But can as well be combined like:

```
[Flags]
public enum Sides
{
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Up = 4,
    Down = 8,

    LeftAndRight = 3,
    UpAndDown = 12,

    AllSides = 15
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the flag attribute, you can read up on it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Lets you treat a set of enums a bit flag set.

Answer (score 1):

the short means that the enum is using short instead of an int as its base type.
as for the flags
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Flags` is an *attribute*; specifically, [`System.FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

It means that the compiler lets you use values of type `TwDG` as a bit-field, i.e., store as many of them as you want in one value like this:

```
var control = TwDG.Control;
var allTogether = TwDG.Control | TwDG.Image | TwDG.Audio;
```

Typically, this is done when some code needs to take different (or optional) actions depending on if one of these flags is set. For example, let's say we want to describe the contents of a video file, which might contain audio and picture. You could write:

```
var imageAndAudio = TwDG.Image | TwDG.Audio;
var muteImage = TwDG.Image;
```

Then, if you wanted to check if the file contains an audio track, you would "pick out" the `Audio` flag like this:

```
var hasAudio = (myValue & TwDG.Audio) != (TwDG) 0;
```

Comment: The compiler lets you do all that anyway, without the Flags attribute. Flags controls parsing and formatting, that's all.

Comment: I stand corrected. Classic example of upgrading "I would never do that" to "*obviously* the compiler won't let me do that".

Answer (score 0):

I've heard them called decorators before (and it is acceptable to label them as such in the community) but for arguments sake and strictly speaking; it is an attribute. It is used to "mark" the enum as a bit flag type.
Here's the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As for [Flag] - you should look here [link text](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/sample_chapter/article.php/c12963)

Short - data time, which used to store enum values.